# I have the following error when I use DropDownlist for 3rd or second time! "failed to load viewstate is being loaded must .."

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms, ispostback

I have a "listview" for showing list of employee and a "dropdownlist" to select department. The following error occurs when I use "DropDownlist" for 3rd or second time:

> "Failed to load viewstate".

The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save "viewstate" during the previous request. For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request."

This is asp.net Webform and I have to use this technology and have no other choice .

```
namespace .Presentation.general
{

public partial class Listg : PageBase
{


    void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = "~/App_MasterPages/empty.Master";
    }
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList();

            GeneralObjectDataSource.SelectParameters["Department"].DefaultValue = "";

            decimal presence = Convert.ToDecimal(Data.EmployeeDB.Create().GetCountEMPOnlineToday());

            decimal visibles = Convert.ToDecimal(Data.EmployeeDB.Create().GetCountVisiblesEmployees());
            visibles = (visibles == 0 ? 1 : visibles);
            PresenceLabel.Text = System.Math.Round((presence / visibles) * 100, 1).ToString() + "% " + string.Format(" ({0})", presence);



        }

    }

     public void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GeneralObjectDataSource.SelectParameters["name"].DefaultValue = Common.Converter.ConvertToFarsiYK(NameTextBox.Text.Trim());



        if (PresenceRadioBottonList.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            GeneralObjectDataSource.SelectParameters["onlyPresence"].DefaultValue = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            GeneralObjectDataSource.SelectParameters["onlyPresence"].DefaultValue = "false";
        }

        DataListView.DataBind();
    }

    public void select_department_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GeneralObjectDataSource.SelectParameters["name"].DefaultValue = "";
        GeneralObjectDataSource.SelectParameters["Department"].DefaultValue = select_department.SelectedItem.Text;
        GeneralObjectDataSource.DataBind();


        DataListView.DataBind();


    }



    private void PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList()
    {
        select_department.DataSource = Biz.EmployeeBO.GetDepartments();
        select_department.DataTextField = "Name";
        select_department.DataValueField = "ID";
        select_department.DataBind();

        select_department.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));
        select_department.SelectedValue = Biz.Settings.SelectedDepartmentID;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is this only locally, when you're developing? Try adding `if (!IsPostBack)` on `Page_PreInit`, but I can't remember if that actually is useable on preinit.

Comment: Thank you . i solve this problem by set the viewstate=false for the list view and viewstate=true for whole page